# Any way to enable stacktraces in MsTest?

Tags: mstest

Sometimes I get errors in a MsTest run and there is to little context to track down the problem, for example:

```
<ErrorInfo>
    <Message>Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Type is not resolved for member 'Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException,Castle.Windsor, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'..</Message>
</ErrorInfo>
```

notice the dots '..' Is there some flag or anything that can make it include the rest of the error? I am running Mstest from commandline.

Comment: I have had some progress not ideal but anyway... Tests are run by a preocess called QTAgent32.exe, by looking into its config file I could see that it actually logs errors to the event log, go figure. The stacktrace was complete there.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can add the errorstacktrace argument:

```
mstest /testcontainer:MyTests.dll /detail:errorstacktrace
```